# Collapse elements by default with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I am using a JavaScript plug in to enable filtering capabilities on a set of site pages. Currently there is nothing to filter the pages on so there is no need to show all the filtering options. What I would like to do is set the current filter jquery to have the filters collapsed by default, rather than extended as they are now. Below is the jquery I am using for the filters.

```
var searchHashName = "#loadSearch-";
var searchTypeKey = "searchType";
var dayIDKey = "dayID";
var currentSearchType = "";
var dayID = "";
var useNavDropdown = true;
var dayTimeSearch = false;
$(function(){
    windowBinder();
    $('#searchContainer').addClass("ui-tabs ui-widget")
    .find("ul").addClass("ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
    .find("li").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-top").hover(
            function(){$(this).addClass("ui-state-hover")},
            function(){$(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover")}
        );
    $('#searchContainer ul').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $('#searchContainer ul a').click(function(){
        var $li = $(this).closest('li');
        currentSearchType = getURLParam(this.href, searchTypeKey);
        if(currentSearchType === "attendee"){
            ConnectAjax.checkLogin(function(result){
                if(result == false){
                    var url = window.location.pathname;
                    $('#templateHeader').load(url + ' #templateHeader');
                    $li.hide().siblings().filter(':visible').first().find('a').click();
                    loginDialog();
                }
                else{
                    $('#templateContent .selectedFilters').show();
                    submitSearch({tabClick:true});
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            //show hide filters
            if(currentSearchType === "all") {$('#templateContent .selectedFilters').hide();}
            else $('#templateContent .selectedFilters').show();

            submitSearch({tabClick:true});
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#searchContainer ul a').bind('click.setCurrent', function(){
        $('#searchContainer li').removeClass('ui-state-active ui-tabs-active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('ui-state-active ui-tabs-active ');
        currentSearchType = getURLParam(this.href, searchTypeKey);
        $('#searchFilters div.searchFilter').hide().filter("#"+currentSearchType+"Search").show();
        $("#searchFilters #"+currentSearchType+"Search .boxed-filter").trigger('filter-onload');
        showHideSortOptions();
    });
    $('#searchContainer li.ui-tabs-active a').triggerHandler('click.setCurrent');

    $('#searchForm .phraseDiv').keywordSearch({ onClear: submitSearch }).css('visibility', 'visible');
    if($('#searchForm .searchPhrase').data('blank') !== true){
        populateHiddenPhrase();
        highlightSearchString();
    }

    $('#searchFilters input[name=profileValueBaseKey]').attr('name','p').val(''); //prevent base key from showing in the address bar
    loadCurrentHash();

    $("#searchResult")
        .on("click", "a.openInPopup", function(){ 
            showDetail(this.href, this.title);
            return false;
        })
        .on('click', '.download', downloadDocs)
        .on("click", ".mapItem", mapItemClick);

    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        submitSearch();
        return false;
    });

    if(useNavDropdown){
        var siteMenuTxt = $('#siteMenuTxt').html();
        var navDropdown = $('<div id="navDropdown"></div>').html('<div class="downLink ui-state-default ui-corner-bl">'+ siteMenuTxt +'<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></div>').prependTo('nav').append($("#mainNav"))
            .hover(
                function(){
                    $('#navDropdown .downLink').addClass('ui-state-hover').removeClass('ui-corner-bl');
                    $('#mainNav').addClass('ui-corner-bl').show();
                },
                function(){
                    $('#navDropdown .downLink').removeClass('ui-state-hover').addClass('ui-corner-bl');
                    $('#mainNav').hide() 
                }
            );
        $('#mainNav').css("position", "absolute").addClass('ui-corner-bl');
    }
    else{
        $("#mainNav").show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Please limit your code to the relevant code in a [mcve]. I'm not sure how `submitAnalyticsInfo` has to do with your filter code, for instance.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thank you for the feedback, I have made the updates. I apologize, as I am widely uneducated in JS, so I was concerned about cutting out what was necessary.